# retraction of closed unit ball to its boundary

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $\overline{}$ be its closed unit ball and $$ its unit sphere. A retraction from $\overline{}$ to $$ is a continuous map $r:\overline{}→$ such that $\left.r\right|_$ is the identity map on $$. When $X$ has finite dimension, no such retraction exists. This statement is wrong in *any* infinite dimensional space $X$.

The following exercise gives an example.

> Let $X$ be $C^0[0,1]$ equipped with supremum norm.
> (a) Let $A : X → X$ be defined by
> $$
> A f(t)={|f(t)+1-2 t(1-{‖f‖})|}-1+2 t(1-{‖f‖}) .
> $$
> Show that $A$ is the identity on $$ and ${‖Af‖}≥\frac17$ for $f∈\overline{}$.
> (b) Deduce that there is a retraction from $\overline{}$ to $$.

My attempt:
(a) Argue by contradiction, suppose $\|Af\|<\frac17$ then $\frac17>Af(t)$ for all $t\in[0,1]$.
Taking $t=1$,
$$\frac17>Af(1)\ge-1+2 (1-{\|f\|})$$So ${‖f‖}>\frac37$.
I don't know how to proceed, can you help me?

The hint is to consider $t_1<t_2$ for which $f\left(t_1\right)=-\frac17$ and $f\left(t_2\right)=-\frac37$.
I don't see why $t_1$ exist.

Comment: How is $Af=f$ when $f\in\Bbb S$?

Comment: @TedShifrin When $f∈$, substitute $‖f‖=1$,$$A f(t)={|f(t)+1-2 t(1-‖f‖)|}-1+2 t(1-‖f‖)=|f(t)+1|-1=f(t)$$since $f(t)+1≥0$.